Access Google consent screen in host machine's browser
I created a simple Quarkus application that uses the Google Calendar API to create some events and containerized it.
When requesting access to the users data however I am not redirected to the consent screen in my host machine (my localhost), instead in the container's logs I see a log "Please open the following address in your browser:"
with redirect uri "http://localhost:8888/Callback" and I have to copy it and paste it in my browser to access the screen.
Here is also a sample of the authorization code (taken from original documentation):
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();

This happens because "localhost" corresponds to the container's ip and not my actual host machine, so let's say I want to make this application public, by hosting it in some cloud provider environment.
What can we do then to make the redirection happen to the client's browser in their host machine?
